# Questions about Debian OpenDLAP configuration

Tags: debian, configuration, openldap, files, slapd

I have the `slapd/stable,now 2.4.57+dfsg-3 amd64` Debian 11 package. I read the [official OpenLDAP documentation](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/) and [Debian article](https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/OpenLDAPSetup).

But I cannot understand the difference between the multiple configuration files.

I know the best practice is to use the dynamic **OLC** (OpenLDAP Configuration) method over the legacy slapd.conf static file.

I saw the package ships with 2 other static configuration files, they are :

- `/etc/default/slapd` (can't find a doc about it)
- `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` (`ldap.conf(5)` which is a different doc from `slapd.conf(5)`)

**My first question is, do I have to use those static files or the OLC method is sufficient ?**

Moreover, in `/etc/default/slapd` file, there is the `SLAPD_SERVICES` option, and in `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`, there is `URI` option. Both are used to set the connection methods.

**What are the differences of these options, and how do they compete ?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I got it.

`/etc/default/slapd` configures some defaults settings related to server properties (like ports, user, group, conf location, etc.).

`/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` configures the OpenLDAP **client**.

`/etc/ldap/slapd.conf` configures the OpenLDAP server statically, which is obsolete by the dynamic OLC.